# How to create a remote event receiver for a list on host web?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, azure, remote-event-receiver

I am trying to to create a remote event receiver for a list on sharepoint online,note am using azure to deploy the web app. I am still a beginner if you could show me the steps to take,been trying several tutorial and i was able to make it work locally but on deploying to azure the remote event receiver doesnt get triggered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create Remote Event Receiver for List on Host Web, the following articles for your reference:

[Attaching Remote Event Receivers to Lists in the Host Web](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/)

[Remote Event Receiver (RER) for Host Web using SharePoint Provider Hosted App in Office 365/SharePoint Online Environment](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/)

**OR**

There are two ways to deploy your event receiver, [Check This Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cb3097f3-d8a7-46f2-ac29-ca8b50747e7f/how-to-add-remote-event-receiver-on-sharepoint-2013-online-custom-list?forum=sharepointcustomization#dca78fcf-9b51-40ca-a4b9-0d5a2c64b609)

Comment: still cant get it to work,i have no idea why

Comment: i tried this http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/steps-to-create-a-remote-event-receiver-for-sharepoint-online-21971.aspx  and use the second type of deployment using wsp file,didnt work

Comment: I tried this one https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/24/creating-a-sharepoint-2013-app-with-azure-web-sites/